# Android Eclipse - Random numbers

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse and Java but have a decent enough amount of experience in Visual Basic.

I'm trying make a basic app and I'm trying to generate a random number to be used to place a button in that numbers position. I've followed some some steps but keep getting stuck, any help is appreciated, thanks.

I'm getting this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setHeight(int) from the type TextView

If anyone can explain to me how to fix it but more importantly why I get it so I can learn then thanks!

```
package com.jordanreece.themetests;

import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Game extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


     Random r0 = new Random();
        int height = r0.nextInt(272 - 20) + 20;

        Random r1 = new Random();
        int width = r1.nextInt(110 - 20) + 20;



    Button.setHeight(height);
    Button.setWidth(width);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of layout did you use?  You're probably going to have to use something like a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout and then use setX() and setY() if you're trying to position it on the screen.  Size it or position it ... You're going to need to setup your button as well.

Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_id_you_assigned_to_your_button_in_the_layout);

Comment: 'Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_id_you_assigned_to_your_button_in_the_layout);' Was the problem thanks, I'm already using relative layout so going try using the set x and y and I'll post my results. Thanks!

Comment: I need a higher reputation to vote, but when I get that I won't forget this haha:) By the way you wouldn't happen to know what to x and y coordinates range are?

Comment: That's one of the harder questions to answer.  There are so many screen sizes.  You can query the device to get the screen width and height and use that to seed your random number.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the setHeight and setWidth methods correctly.

```
Button.setHeight(int);
```

You are required to create the object first.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

then using the newly created object you do

```
btn.setHeight(int)
btn.setWidth(int)
```

I suggest reading up on [static methods](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html) to learn more about the static keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to sort it out now and you're right, thanks for the link especially though, its what I want when I'm try to learn something new!